# jquery datepicker beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends minus 1 day?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a program that needs datepicker to allow chooseable dates sunday - thursday rather than the $.datepicker.noWekeends function of Monday - Friday.

Is there a simple way to enable this with beforeShowDay?  I can't find anything related to this.  If not is there a way to use "days of week" array or something along those lines to manually code the allowed days of week?

```
 $(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $('#sched_macs_button').show(300);

        },
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: dateToday
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Array, thanks for your consideration.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $('#sched_macs_button').show(300);
        },
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (day) {
            var day = day.getDay();
            if (day == 5 || day == 6) {
                return [false, "somecssclass"]
            } else {
                return [true, "someothercssclass"]
            }
        },
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: dateToday
    });
```